# Retaining topic branch commits with git-svn dcommit

Tags: git, git-svn

I started using git-svn recently. My git work flow is like this.
git checkout master
git svn rebase
git checkout -b topicbranch
..changes
git commit
git checkout master
git merge topicbranch
git svn rebase
git dcommit

Problem is that, whenever I do dcommit the only final merge commit of topic branch is seen in svn repository. I want to see the svn commits corresponds to individual git commits made in topic branch.

Is their any way to do it. Or this is the recommended default behavior.

Comment: Your final command should read `git svn dcommit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(`git rebase` with no additional arguments is an error, so I suspect you're not accurately describing what you're doing.  Also, you've missed out the `svn` in `git svn dcommit`.)

However, it looks to me as if the problem is that you're merging `topicbranch` into `master` without rebasing it first.  That means that if this doesn't turn out to be a fast-forward merge, there'll be a merge commit added in the git history, and that can only be represented by a single commit in Subversion.  After you've worked on your topic branch, try the following instead:

```
# make sure you're on the right branch first:
git checkout topicbranch 
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge topicbranch
git svn rebase
git svn dcommit
```

Comment: will that squash the commits into one in svn ? or is that the proper way to avid that?

Comment: @loosecannon: if you do what I've suggested in my answer, the commits won't be squashed together in svn - that's the point.